# Vue component throws errors before rendered?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vuex

The `Home` view contains two components. `Filter` and `Results`. The component `Results` depends heavily on the results of vuex store data that is affected by the  `Filter` component. After the filters are applied and the user clicks on a button in `Filter` the needed data for `Results` is created in the store and this component should be then rendered below `Filter`.

Here is the problem. When I open the `Home` view, the `Results` component throws errors in the console like `"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`. This is expected as the data does not exist yet. I tried to render `Results` conditionally with `<Results v-if="$store.state.data != {}" />`. This prevents the rendering when the user enters the page and renders `Results` once the data is loaded after the button is clicked, but nevertheless `Results` throws the same errors as before when the page is opened.

One potential solution I have is that I can enter dummy data in the store to prevent errors (and then render with other condition). But there must be a way that works without dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already identified the solution yourself: Using default dummy data on the object itself.

This would be the standard and optimal approach.

If you do this, you need to realise that Vuex doesn't work well with nested, relation data.

Typically, you'd want to normalise your data so that's flat and mapped via relationships.

You can learn more about the need to normalise state here

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/

It's about Redux, but the concepts are relevant to Vuex too.

To do this, you'd use [Vue ORM](https://vuex-orm.org/) to normalise the complex data. After normalisation, the objects in the Vuex will be much easier to manage, update and query.

Doing this also prevents Vuex from throwing errors when you attempt to access/update data from a nested object where the data doesn't currently exist (think nested data where it's comments and replies to comments).

This also has the added benefits of making your data easier to work with and understand programatically.